# Internal Server Error when uploading large files (AWS e Django)

Tags: python, django, apache, file-upload, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Django API in AWS that is manage by Elastic Beanstalk, the compose it is, EC2, RDS and for storage is the S3.

So, the upload file work fine until 200MB, when is more it, the foloowing  exception is throwed:

**The Postman app:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
        <p>The server encountered an internal error or
           misconfiguration and was unable to complete
           your request.
        </p>
        <p>Please contact the server administrator at
           root@localhost to inform them of the time this error 
           occurred, and the actions you performed just before this 
           error.
        </p>
        <p>More information about this error may be available
           in the server error log.
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**The Elastic Beanstalk log:**

```
MemoryError
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred
```

**Some observation:**

- The S3 bucket limit per file is 5T
- In my local server all works fine

Comment: What's the upload script look like?

Comment: Is a Django FileField field and i use the django-storages for manage it

Comment: what's the available RAM on the instance? if you fill it up during the file process, you'll definitely run into issues, hence the `MemoryError`

Comment: Are you able to replicate this locally or on a dev environment with `DEBUG=True`?

Comment: @mattjegan, It is a dev environment at AWS with DEBUG=True

Comment: @Capsule, I will do a teste, increase the instance from t2.micro to t2.small, thank's

Comment: Thank you @Capsule, the problem was solved increasing the instance. Someone know how i close this question?

Comment: @user3358519 note that by increasing the instance size you only temporarily fix the issue until some file is uploaded that hits the new instances limits.

Comment: Really @mattjegan, we are work toward optimized the uplad process now, but this question was solved.

Comment: check your file upload size limit in your web server